# google maps set marker depending on conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using google maps api and for implementing some task i have to conditions (two radibuttons actually):

1."Enter address manually" - it is by default when user opens page

2."Set marker on the map" - the second condition.

The question is related with second conditions, i want to set marker on map if user click second radio button.

I've tried to use this following code, but it doesn't work outside of `initialize` function.
I need to give user opportunity set marker on map only if the second condition is checked.

For more information tale a look at [THIS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4mtyu/59/)

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event){
var marker_position = event.latLng;   
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                draggable: false
            }); 
marker.setPosition(marker_position);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if the radio is checked inside the click handler

```
if($('#set-marker').is(':checked')) {
  //add marker
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qo7rfau6/

Answer (score 0):

note, you need to include the jquery library for the following code to work.
Add a check for the radio button inside the listener

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event){
    // check if radio button is checked
    if ($('#set-marker').is(':checked')) {
        var marker_position = event.latLng;   
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            draggable: false
        }); 
       marker.setPosition(marker_position);
    }
})
```